# how to make predicates function? in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

i'm trying to make predicates functions

datatype definition

```
(define-datatype expression expression?
  (const-exp (num number?))
  (var-exp (var symbol?))
  (zero?-exp (exp1 expression?))
  (diff-exp (exp1 expression?)
            (exp2 expression?)))
```

if argument is #2(struct:const-exp 7) then print #t

if argument is #2(struct:var-exp x) then print #f

```
(define const-exp? ... )
```

it would be honor if you help me

Comment: `define-datatype` does not exist in Scheme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my guess is that you are studying [Essentials of Programming Languages](http://www.eopl3.com) and probably use [Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/eopl/index.html) as your environment.

If that is true, you should probably use [cases](http://docs.racket-lang.org/eopl/index.html?q=cases#%28form._%28%28lib._eopl%2Feopl..rkt%29._cases%29%29) here:

```
(define (const-exp? e)
  (cases expression e
    (const-exp (num) #t)
    (else #f)))
```

then

```
> (const-exp? (const-exp 7))
#t
> (const-exp? (var-exp 'x))
#f
```